# How to a2ensite and a2dissite?

Tags: redhat, httpd

I'm logged into a Linux server.  I think it's a Red Hat distribution.

The commands `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` are not available. 
In the `/etc/httpd` directory, I don't see any mention of `sites-enabled` or `sites-available`.

I'm pretty sure the site is currently executing the directives of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` .  I would like to do a `a2dissite ssl`, then reload the Web Server. How to do achieve this ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`a2ensite` etc. are commands available in Debian-based systems and that are not available in RH-based distributions.

What they do is to manage symbolic links from configuration file parts in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `mods-available` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and so on. E.g. if you have a vhost defined in a config file `/etc/apache2/sites-avaible/example.com`, `a2ensite example.com` would create a symlink to this file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and reload the apache config. The main Apache config file contains lines that include every file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and thus, they get incorporated into the runtime  config.

It's quite easy to mimic this structure in RHEL. Add two directories in `/etc/httpd/` named `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` and add your vhosts into files in `sites-available`. After that, add a line

```
include ../sites-enabled
```

to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. You can now create symlinks to `sites-enabled` and then reload the config with `service httpd reload` or `apachectl`.

Comment: Ahh i see. So basically /etc/httpd/conf.d is acting at as the equivalent of sites-enabled.  So just removing ssl.conf from that directory and restarting/reloading httpd picked up my changes.  That's cool

Answer (score 4):

As an add-on to Sven's excellent answer, two scripts that mimic the behaviour of a2ensite and a2dissite. The original ensite.sh can be found on [Github](https://gist.github.com/mateusg/3251671)

**a2ensite.sh**

```
#!bin/bash
# Enable a site, just like the a2ensite command.

SITES_AVAILABLE_CONFIG_DIR="/etc/httpd/sites-available";
SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR="/etc/httpd/sites-enabled";

if [ $1 ]; then
  if [ -f "${SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR}/${1}" ]; then
    echo "Site ${1} was already enabled!";
  elif [ ! -w $SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR ]; then
    echo "You don't have permission to do this. Try to run the command as root."
  elif [ -f "${SITES_AVAILABLE_CONFIG_DIR}/${1}" ]; then
    echo "Enabling site ${1}...";
    ln -s $SITES_AVAILABLE_CONFIG_DIR/$1 $SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR/$1
    echo "done!"
 else
   echo "Site not found!"
fi
else
  echo "Please, inform the name of the site to be enabled."
fi
```

**a2dissite.sh**

```
#!bin/bash
# Disable a site, just like a2dissite command, from Apache2.

SITES_AVAILABLE_CONFIG_DIR="/etc/httpd/sites-available";
SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR="/etc/httpd/sites-enabled";

if [ $1 ]; then
  if [ ! -f "${SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR}/${1}" ]; then
    echo "Site ${1} was already disabled!";
  elif [ ! -w $SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR ]; then
    echo "You don't have permission to do this. Try to run the command as root."
  elif [ -f "${SITES_AVAILABLE_CONFIG_DIR}/${1}" ]; then
    echo "Disabling site ${1}...";
    unlink $SITES_ENABLED_CONFIG_DIR/$1
    echo "done!"
  else
    echo "Site not found!"
  fi
else
  echo "Please, inform the name of the site to be enabled."
fi
```

Comment: what should the "name of the site" be?